# what exactly is the difference between warning and error in jupyter notebook?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, object-detection, yolo

I am following an instruction in github (https://github.com/experiencor/keras-yolo3) to learn object detection by YOLO-3.
after running code below:

```
!python train.py -c config.json
```

I received several messages in the output, and I am trying to understand what each meanS.

One of them is as below:

```
WARNING:tensorflow:From train.py:26: The name tf.keras.backend.set_session is deprecated. Please use tf.compat.v1.keras.backend.set_session instead.
```

1. Is that, do I have to fix the meantion part of code (tf.keras.backend.set_session) since it is "deprecated" as said here?
2. How does a warning generally, and specifically this warning may effect my final model if not to be fixed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Answer one : long story short, a deprecated function is an old one, replaced by something (hopefully) better, and still there for retro-compatibility. You can use it but will not get the latest development/support and, at some point, your code will not be functional anymore (since the faith of a deprecated function is to disappear in a future release).

Answer two :

> Warning messages are typically issued in situations where it is useful to alert the user of some condition in a program, where that condition (normally) doesn’t warrant raising an exception and terminating the program. For example, one might want to issue a warning when a program uses an obsolete module.

https://docs.python.org/3/library/warnings.html

All in all, here, the interpreter just warms you that you are using a function that you will not be able to use in the future.